# Background execvp : how to do it properly?

Tags: c, shell, posix

Like many others, I'm trying to simulate a shell. I've gotten to use the `execvp` properly on a string coming from the user. The string is parsed and an array of strings is generated (each word has its array, split on the `space` character), including a `NULL` at the very end.

When I find that the last word entered by the user is `&`, I set a flag up to notify my shell that the command is to be executed in the background while letting the user input another command right away. The "background-executed" command sees its `&` replaced by a `NULL` character within the array of strings passed to `execvp`.

As it is, I've been trying to use a `pthread` to run the process in the background, but it's acting somewhat weird: the command passed to `execvp` through the thread's function requires me to press two times `ENTER` after sending the command.

Here is my simplified `main` function that is to simulate a shell:

```
int main (void) {

    fprintf (stdout, "%% ");

    bool running = true;

    while(running) {

        /* Ask for an instruction and parses it. */
        char** args = query_and_split_input();

        /* Executing the commands. */
        if (args == NULL) {  // error while reading input
            running = false;
        } else {
            printf("shell processing new command\n");

            int count = count_words(args);
            split_line* line = form_split_line(args, count);
            Expression* ast = parse_line(line, 0, line->size - 1);

            if(line->thread_flag) {
                pthread_t cmd_thr;

                /* Setting up the content of the thread. */
                thread_data_t       thr_data;
                thr_data.ast        = *ast;
                thr_data.line       = *line;

                /* Executing the thread. */
                int thr_err;
                if ((thr_err = pthread_create(&cmd_thr, NULL, thr_func, &thr_data))) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "error: pthread_create, rc: %d\n", thr_err);
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                printf("thread has been created.\n");

            } else {
                run_shell(args);
            }
            free(line);

            printf("done running shell on one command\n");
        }
    }

    /* We're all done here. See you! */
    printf("Bye!\n");
    exit (0);
}
```

Here is my thread's function:

```
void *thr_func(void *arg) {
    thread_data_t *data = (thread_data_t *)arg;

    data->line.content[data->line.size-1] = NULL;  // to replace the trailing '&' from the command
    run_shell(data->line.content);

    printf("thread should have ran the command\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

And the actual line that runs a command:

```
void run_shell(char** args) {

    /* Forking. */
    int status;
    pid_t    pid; /* Right here, the created THREAD somehow awaits a second 'ENTER' before going on and executing the next instruction that forks the process. This is the subject of my first question. */
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed");

    } else if (pid == 0) {  // child
        printf("Child executing the command.\n");

        /* Executing the commands. */
        execvp(args[0], args);

        /* Child process failed. */
        printf("execvp didn't finish properly: running exit on child process\n");
        exit(-1);


    } else {  // back in parent
        waitpid(-1, &status, 0);  // wait for child to finish

        if (WIFEXITED(status)) { printf("OK: Child exited with exit status %d.\n", WEXITSTATUS(status)); }
        else { printf("ERROR: Child has not terminated correctly. Status is: %d\n", status); }

        free(args);
        printf("Terminating parent of the child.\n");
    }
}
```

So basically, as an example, what `run_shell(args)` receives is either `["echo","bob","is","great",NULL]` (in the case of a sequential execution) or `["echo","bob","is","great",NULL,NULL]` (in the case of a command to be executed in the background).

I've left the `printf` traces since it might help you understand the execution flow.

If I input `echo bob is great`, the output (printf traces) is:

```
shell processing new command
Child executing the command.
bob is great
OK: Child exited with exit status 0.
Terminating parent of the child.
done running shell on one command
```

However, if I input `echo bob is great &`, the output is:

```
shell processing new command
thread has been created.
done running shell on one command
```

And then I actually need to press `ENTER` again to obtain the following output:

```
Child executing the command.
bob is great
OK: Child exited with exit status 0.
Terminating parent of the child.
thread should have ran the command
```

(On that last execution, I also get traces of my function that queries and parses the input of the user, but that seemed irrelevant so I abstracted this whole part.)

**So my questions are**:

1. How comes the created thread awaits a second `ENTER` before running the `execvp` ? (`thr_func` stops executing `run_shell` and awaits the second `ENTER` right before the `pid = fork();` instruction)
2. Do I have the right approach to solve the problem at hand? (Trying to execute a shell command in the background.)

Comment: `execxxx()` does not invoke a (sub)shell. Your `&` is just an argument. You're on your own now....

Comment: @wildplasser I'm not sure I understand what you mean. As it is, when I detect a `&`, I try to invoke a subshell myself since indeed `execxxx()` does not do such a thing. That's why I've been trying to start a `pthread` in the first place to then `fork()` from there and `execvp` within it afterward.

Comment: `execvp(args[0], args);` does not run a `/bin/sh`

Comment: @wildplasser Is this to answer my first question? As it is, `execvp(args[0], args);` when ran on `args = ["echo","bob",NULL]` properly finds the `echo` command and executes it properly. I've edited my OP since I had forgotten to mention that `args` contains the command itself within `args[0]`: that might have been the confusion.

Comment: Yes, that is `/bin/echo`. To execute a shell, you'll need at least `/bin/sh`

Comment: @wildplasser I don't think that we are allowed to use `/bin/sh` for the purpose of our assignment since it automatically does most of the word required by the assignment itself (parsing, creating an abstract syntax tree, redirecting output when required, etc.).

Comment: Sorry, I  misread. So your problem is in parsing the `&` from the commandline and not waiting for the child process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187824/discussion-between-payne-and-wildplasser).

Comment: Don't combine threads with fork. You can fork without starting a new thread. Forking threaded code is complicated.

Comment: @rici but if I use a `fork` instead of a `pthread`, don't I need to use `wait` which then precisely prevents my main process from allowing the user to input new commands while awaiting for the forked process to finish ?

Comment: The traditional way to do this is to do the wait in a SIGCHLD signal handler.

Comment: Shells don't do threads. When a shell sees <command> `&` it forks a separate process.

Comment: @rici I've been reading on SIGCHLD and it seems to be what I need to go for. Thanks for the cue. I'll keep reading and trying things out.

Comment: @rici does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18437957/9768291) seem to be the way to go? I added a `fork` instead of my `pthread` creation, and ensured that `waitpid` was absent from the code executed by the parent of forked process. Instead, I declared at the very beginning of my `main` function a signal handler `signal(SIGCHLD, my_signal_handler);`. It is still unclear to me if I should simply use `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);`. Also, how would I go about the `free` of things that were malloc'd for the child-process's purposes, but that need to released after the child is done?

Comment: You certainly need to do something in the signal handler:  "wait" for the child and collect its status. (Wait won't block.) But you can't call free in a signal handler so you'll need to defer that until somewhere in the main handler loop. Set a flag in the signal handler and check it somewhere in the read loop.

Comment: the shell must create a new process.  A thread is not valid in this case, as it uses the same virtual space as the shell and you cannot `exec*` it.  All one process threads share the same virtual address space, and `execvp` has whole process semantics.  When you exec, you substitute alll the threads by one new process with only one thread of execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a thread to simulate a process.  Well, strictly you can, but there's no use on doing that.  The problem is that all the threads belonging to a process share the same virtual address space.  There's no reason to create a thread, as you finally need to `fork()` to create a new process (you'll need this for reasons explained below), so why to create two threads of execution if one of them will be stopped all the time just waiting for the subprocess to finish.  There's no use on this schema.

The need of a `fork()` system call comes historically to make a simple call to create a new process (with different virtual memory map) to allow for a new program to be able to be executed.  You need to create a new, complete process before calling `exec(2)` system call, because the process address space will be overwritten by the text and data segments of the new program.  If you do this in a thread, you'll be overwriting the whole process address space (this is the shell) and killing all the threads you can have running on behalf of that process.  The schema to follow is (pseudocode):

```
/* create pipes for redirection here, before fork()ing, so they are available
 * in the parent process and the child process */
int fds[2];
if (pipe(fds) < 0) { /* error */
    ... /* do error treatment */
}
pid_t child_pid = fork();
switch(child_pid) {
case -1: /* fork failed for some reason, no subprocess created */
    ...
    break;
case 0: /* this code is executed in the childd process, do redirections
         * here on pipes acquired ***before*** the fork() call */
        if (dup2(0 /* or 1, or 2... */, fds[0 /* or 1, or 2... */]) < 0) { /* error */
            ... /* do error management, considering you are in a different process now */
        }
        execvpe(argc, argv, envp);
        ... /* do error management, as execvpe failed (exec* is non-returning if ok) */
        break; /* or exit(2) or whatever */ 
    default: /* we are the parent, use the return value to track the child */
        save_child_pid(child_pid);
        ... /* close the unused file descriptors */
        close(fds[1 /* or 0, or 2, ... */]);
        ... /* more bookkeeping */
        /* next depends on if you have to wait for the child or not */
        wait*(...);  /* wait has several flavours */
} /* switch */
```

Exec and fork system calls are separated by two reasons:

- you need to be able to do housekeeping between both calls to execute the actual redirections in the child before `exec()`.
- there was a time when unix was not multitasking or protected, and the exec call just replaced all the memory in the system with the new program to execute (including kernel code, to cope with the fact that an unprotected system could be corrupted by the executing program)  This was common in old operating systems and I've seen it on systems like CP/M or TRS-DOS.  The implementation in unix conserved almost all the semantics of exec() call and added with fork() the unavailable functionality only.  This was good, as it allowed both, parent and child processes to do the necessary bookkeeping when the time for pipes came.

Only if you need a different thread to communicate with each child is when you probably can use a different thread to do the task.  But think that a thread shares all the virtual space with the parent (case we can talk about a parent/child relationship between threads) and if you do an exec call you'll get that virtual space overwritten for the whole process (all threads there)

Comment: I used a thread because I wanted to call `exec` in such a way that it wouldn't block the main process, but while still being able to `wait` on the child. That is my error. Thank you.

Comment: @payne, if you call exec in a thread you'll kill all threads in that process, as the whole virtual address space will be overwritten by the new program load.  Exec doesn't create a new address space, as it does not create a new process, that's the task of `fork()` system call.