# wait() SIGCHLD and the exit status

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system

What is the difference between exit status and `SIGCHLD` in Linux?

After the child terminates, a `SIGCHLD` signal is sent to activate the parent (blocked by `wait()` ), so why do we need an exit status of the child?  I can't find the link between `SIGCHLD` and exit status.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does parent process get the termination status through wait from a child process which calls \_exit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6749475). Also see [Capturing exit status code of child process](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27306764) and [Do I need to do anything with a SIGCHLD handler if I am just using wait() to wait for 1 child to finish at a time?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18437779)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exit status of the child process is the value it returns to the parent process via the `exit()` (or `_exit()`) system call. This is a simple integer that typically indicates success or failure of the child process, where zero indicates success (by convention).

SIGCHLD is a signal sent to the parent process when the child terminates. It simply notifies the waiting parent that the child has terminated.

A combination of the two is used to communicate the execution results of the child process back to its parent. The signal tells the parent when the child has exited, and the exit status tells the parent what the execution results of the child are. The parent cannot retrieve the child's exit status until it receives a signal (or a return from `wait()` or `waitpid()`), indicating that the child has exited.

The child can communicate its execution result back to its parent in several ways (various IPC mechanisms, file I/O, etc.), but the simplest way is using `exit()` and `wait()` to send an integer status code from child to parent.

If the parent process does not care what the child execution status is, it can simply ignore the child's exit code returned from `wait()`. On the other hand, complex systems may need to know what the exit status is in order to re-start (`fork()`) a new instance of the child process, or perhaps execute some other program if the child process did (or did not) complete its task properly.

Comment: thank you verry much sir , now i understand the combination of the signal and the exit status .

Answer (score 6):

The exit status is returned by a process (via a call to `exit`) to tell its parent whether or not it succeeded.

When the parent process calls `wait` or `waitpid`, it receives that exit status (and in the case of `waitpid`, the child's pid) and can make decisions based on that value.

If the parent receives a `SIGCHLD` signal, all that tells the process is that one of its child processes finished.  It does not give the parent any information about the pid or exit status of the child.  It's a way to asynchronously tell the parent that it's time to call `wait` or `waitpid`.

Comment: thank you sir , so the signal is giving the "go" to the parent to get the exit status of the child via wait .